# Writing a test_login for a Flask app with pytest and coverage

Tags: flask, pytest, code-coverage

I'm new to **Flask** and **Pytest** and I didn't created the full application I'm working with it.

That said, I succeeded so far in doing this (simplified yet functional example):

`conftest.py`

```py
import os
import pytest
from views import application

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def _demo():
    with application.test_request_context(
        path="/login", method="POST", data={"user": "demo", "password": "demo123"}):
        yield
```

`test_basic.py`

```py
import pytest
from views.autocomplete import autocomplete, best_guess
from views.auth import check_auth, is_logged_in, logout, login

def test_is_logged_in(_demo):
    """res -> tuple(flask.wrappers.Response)"""
    res = is_logged_in()[0]
    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert res.data == b'{"username":"demo"}\n'

def test_best_guess_not_found(_demo):
    """res -> tuple(flask.wrappers.Response)"""
    res = best_guess("ttll")[0]
    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert res.data == b'{"message":"Could not find search query"}\n'
```

So, in essence, I create a `pytest.fixture` so to pass it to my tests that require to be logged in and that works.

However, when checking `coverage`, it states that **`login()`**:

`auth.py`

```py
from functools import wraps
from flask import session, request, jsonify
from passlib.handlers.argon2 import argon2
from db import User
from views import application
from views.postgres import get_db_session

def check_auth(username, password):
...

@application.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    username = request.form["name"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    if not check_auth(username, password):
        return jsonify(error="Invalid Credentials. Please try again."), 401
    session["user"] = username
    session.update()
    return jsonify(success="Authenticated", username=username), 200
```

is **not being tested** (covered). How come?

So, if I need to write an explicit `def test_login():...`, how would I do it?

My attempts so far had only faced failures, like
`werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

```py
----> 1 login()

~/app/views/auth.py in login()
     43 @application.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
     44 def login():
---> 45     username = request.form["name"]
     46     password = request.form["password"]
     47     if not check_auth(username, password):

/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    440             if len(lst) > 0:
    441                 return lst[0]
--> 442         raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
    443
    444     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Since my `login()` does not take arguments, I honestly don't know how to pass what is missed, yet I played vainly with `flask.request` or `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an acceptable solution. In the end, the elements I need are there already in `_demo`, a `pytest.fixture`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def _demo():
    with application.test_request_context(path="/login", method="POST", data={"user": "demo", "password": "demo123"}):
        yield
```

and then:

```py
def test_login_logout(_demo):
    """res -> tuple(flask.wrappers.Response)"""
    kv = dict(
        [
            (check_health, b'{"health":"ok"}\n'),
            (login, b'{"success":"Authenticated","username":"demo"}\n'),
            (is_logged_in, b'{"username":"demo"}\n'),
            (logout, b'{"success":"logged out"}\n'),
        ]
    )
    for func, msg in kv.items():
        res = func()[0]
        assert res.status_code == 200
        assert res.data == msg
```

will give me full coverage of the functions/modules I want to test.